# Twitterの画像サイズ制限について。1辺が4049pxlを超えるもの、はどこで確認できますか？

Tags: twitter, 画像

Twitterでダウンロード可能な「最大画像サイズ」及び「最大画像ファイル容量」について調査しています。試しに画像ファイ容量が大きい画像をアップロード後、ダウンロードしてみたら、「1MB」にも満たないファイル容量でした。

Q1.[1辺が4049pxlを超えるもの](https://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/hl?a=20191216-00000003-giz-sci)とありますが、この仕様はどのドキュメントで確認できますか？
・[画像は5MB以下、GIF画像はモバイル端末なら5MBまで、twitter.comなら15MBまで追加できます。](https://help.twitter.com/ja/using-twitter/tweeting-gifs-and-pictures)
・[Photos can be up to 5MB; animated GIFs can be up to 5MB on mobile, and up to 15MB on web.](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/tweeting-gifs-and-pictures)

Q2.ダウンロード可能なファイル要件は、「1辺が4049pxlを超えないもの」か「5MB以下」の何れかを満たす場合ですか？

Comment: アップロードとダウンロードの話を混同していませんか？

Comment: この質問の前提に、アップロードした画像と同じ画像がダウンロードできることがあると思いますが、Twitterはそれが可能なのでしょうか。それを保証しないと、アップロード画像の仕様を調べたところで意味が無いです。

Comment: https://www.gizmodo.jp/2019/12/twitter-high-image.html

Comment: アップロード画像はある一定の制限を受け、その制限を受けた画像がダウンロード可能になると思うのですが、その制限(特に一辺に関して)はTwitterドキュメントに記載されていますか？

Comment: 「追加できる」画像＝Twitter内に保持される画像＝ダウンロードできる画像　とは限らないかと。Dropbox他、ドライブ的なサービスと違って、画像に最適化が入って改変されても不思議ではないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参照されているYahoo!ニュースの原文はGizmodoのこちらの記事かと思われます。

- [Twitterの写真がめっちゃ高解像度になりました](https://www.gizmodo.jp/2019/12/twitter-high-image.html)

Yahoo!ニュースのものではリンクが欠落していますが、原文には載っています。

[Twitter社のエンジニアの方の一連のツイート](https://twitter.com/NolanOBrien/status/1204557498990002176)が出典で、そのうち[こちら](https://twitter.com/NolanOBrien/status/1204842518208057344)にまとめがあります。

> Q1.1辺が4049pxlを超えるものとありますが、この仕様はどのドキュメントで確認できますか？

該当するドキュメントは[メディアのアップロード > メディアのベストプラクティス](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices)辺りかと思いますが、ここに明記はされていません。上記ツイート中の

> 2) if it is over 4096 in any dimension, we will transcode

を根拠としていると思われます(4049pxというのはキリが悪いので4096のtypoと考えて良いかと思います)。

> Q2.ダウンロード可能なファイル要件は、「1辺が4049pxlを超えないもの」か「5MB以下」の何れかを満たす場合ですか？

同様のツイートより

> 2) if it is over 4096 in any dimension, we will transcode
>   3) if it is over 5 MBs, we will transcode

とありますので、双方を満たす必要があります。